# Converting boost::dynamic_bitset to string gives 8x size increase

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I am trying to turn a `boost::dynamic_bitset` into a `string` so I can pass it to a compression function. I am able to convert it using `boost::to_string` but it leads to 8x more bits. When I convert back from `string` to `boost::dynamic_bitset`, it doesn't reduce 8x the amount of bits used, which would solve my problem as it would lead to the total amount of space used would eventually be the original amount of bits compressed.

I am looking to either stop the 8x increase when going from `boost::dynamic_bitset` -> `string`, or reduce the space used 8x when going from `boost::dynamic_bitset` -> `string`.

The data stored in `boost::dynamic_bitset` is coming from a binary file. [Here is the one I am using](https://dbr.ee/AYq0), but theoretically any file with binary data should work.

When outputting amount of bits, I am calling `string.size()` which returns the size in terms of bytes, hence why I am multiplying by 8. `boost::dynamic_bitset.size()` returns size in terms of bits, so my output should be comparing apples to apples, assuming that is all correct.

Here is the output I am currently getting:

```
Dynamic bitset input bits = 6431936
String from dynamic_bitset bits = 51455488
Dynamic bitset from string bits = 51455488
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <boost/math/cstdfloat/cstdfloat_types.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>

typedef boost::float32_t float32;
typedef boost::uint32_t uint32;

int main() {
   std::vector<unsigned char> data;
   unsigned char *cp;
   float32 value = 8.0;
   boost::uint32_t internal;
   std::memcpy( &internal , &value , sizeof( value ) );

   std::ifstream fin("ex.bin", std::ios::binary);

   while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&internal), sizeof(uint32))) {
      std::memcpy( &value, &internal , sizeof( internal ) );
      cp = (unsigned char *)&internal;

      for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
         data.push_back(*cp);
         ++cp;
      }
   }

   boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> bitset;
   std::string buffer;

   bitset.init_from_block_range(data.begin(), data.end());

   std::cout << "Dynamic bitset input bits = " << bitset.size() << "\n";

   boost::to_string(bitset, buffer);

   std::cout << "String from dynamic_bitset bits = " << buffer.size()*8 << "\n";

   boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> from_str(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

   std::cout << "Dynamic bitset from string bits = " << from_str.size() << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're comparing byte count to bit count?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. It's not clear where those numbers come from, let alone what their unit is.

Comment: where are the number you are quoting coming from?

Comment: Looks like you are violating the requirements of the bitset's constructor: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons4. `std::string` uses `char` but your bitset is using `unsigned char`

Comment: Updated the example with better content hopefully

Comment: Is the use of Snappy at all relevant to your problem or is it just the contstruction of the bitset? Please do provide a MCVE, which should contain a simple `main()`, required includes and nothing superfluous. BTW: As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have updated the problem with a runnable main, and a simplified problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `size()` method on C++ containers idiomatically refers to the number of elements, not to the number of bytes.

`std::string::size()` gives you the count of `char` values in the string, while `boost::dynamic_bitset::size()` returns the number of *bits* stored in it; as you initialized it from n=`buffer.size()` "blocks" of 8 bits each (`char` is 8 bit on pretty much any "normal" platform), it's completely expected that the size it returns is 8 times as big, while the actual consumed memory is exactly the same.

---

***Edit***: after the last modification, the problem is now completely different.

`boost::to_string` doesn't output the internal compact representation, but generates a human-readable string made of actual `'0'` and `'1'` characters, which does result in an 8x increase of required size (the output is a sequence of 8 bit bytes, of which just one bit is effectively used).

Comment: Thank you for point that out. I believe I have correctly updated that information to reflect that, and am having a similar but different problem.

Comment: @TommyMcDonald you changed completely the problem text! The problem you are experiencing now is that `to_string` doesn't output the internal compact representation, but generates a string made of actual `'0'` and `'1'` characters, which does result in an 8x increase of required size (the output is 8 bit bytes, of which just one bit is effectively used).

Comment: Yes, I changed the question to where I was able to figure out based on the responses. I tried creating a new question, but it was marked duplicate, so I didn't know what else to do besides updating this one, with the real problem the entire time.

Comment: I have been able to copy dynamic_bitset to string directly using boost::to_block_range(input, std::back_inserter(buffer)) but then the compression algorithm function Im trying to use thats expecting a string doesn't work. Might be out of the scope of this question. Tried to include info about the compression library but was told to remove it.